# Jquery AJAX related data elements not returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I’m having some trouble getting some jQuery to return values.  I have similar code to this executing for modal examples however the three variables below do not return and need to be passed to the Ajax call.  I know the procedure is triggering as it triggers an alert when I add that code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

I would also like to disabled these links from the success function upon return.  I am unsure how to disabled both the like and dislike link.  Any help here would be awesome as well.

result:
http://localhost:8000/flag/like?conid=&contype=&val=

link example

```
<a href="#" class="like" data-val="1" data-contype="picture" data-conid="43"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> </a>
<a href="#" class="like" data-val="2" data-contype="picture" data-conid="43"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i></a>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", "a.like", function(e){
            var conid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('conid');
            var contype = $(e.relatedTarget).data('contype');
            var val = $(e.relatedTarget).data('val');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET", 
                data: {"conid": conid,"contype": contype,"val": val},
                url: "{{ url('flag/like') }}", 
                success: function(result){             
                     $("#results").html(result);         
                 }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why `e.relatedTarget` and not `this`? What troubleshooting have you done - any console errors, are your variables populated before the AJAX, is your endpoint getting hit, does everything being passed to/from look alright in the Network tab, etc?

Comment: I originally tried this and it didn't work. Just tried it again and now it works... thank you... everything's populated and looks fine... now i'm curious as to how to disable the links based of conid and contype thanks